# UIDevice properties not working in static library

Tags: properties, uidevice

I have created a static library in Iphone SDK in which I used some UIDevice properties.
When I run the app, this xcode show this error
UIDevice Undeclared... Even the same code is running perfectly fine while I don't create static libraries and just build the source files.

Comment: I'm getting this too in my new static library, for UIDevice and also for UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification - the references worked fine in my main app. They are both in UIKit.framework, which I've added to my library's 'Link Binaries With Libraries' list, but I get undeclared errors.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Have you tried adding

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

...to the top of your class .h file?  I was running into similar problems as you are having, but when I added that import into my .h files that seemed to fix a lot of the errors.